# UPDATE STATEMENT 2 tables c#

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

my problem is that i tried all kind of solutions but it doesnt update my table here is my code behind of the button_click update:

```
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            string fileName = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
            FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("Files/" + fileName));
            SqlConnection cnx = new SqlConnection();
            cnx.ConnectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["str"].ConnectionString;

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Update Appel_offre set Titre_ao='" + TextBox4.Text + "',Description_ao='" + TextBox5.Text + "',Cout='" + TextBox6.Text + "',Type='" + DropDownList3.Text + "',Date='" + TextBox8.Text + "',Echeance='" + TextBox9.Text + "',Reference='" + TextBox7.Text + "',Piece_jointe='" + "Files/" + fileName + "',filename='" + fileName + "' where Id_ao = '" + Session["Id_ao"] + "' ", cnx);
            SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("Update Lot set Description=@desc,Reference=@ref,Type=@type where Titre = '" + Dropdownlst.SelectedItem.Value + "'",cnx);
            cnx.Open();
            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@desc", TextBox2.Text );
            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ref", TextBox3.Text );
            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@type", DropDownList2.Text );

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();

            cnx.Close();

            if (IsPostBack)
            {
                conff.Visible = true;
            }


        }
```

Comment: You get any exception or error message? What is your update queries looks like after your add values? Did you debug your code? Can you please be more specific about your problem? Also parameterize your all variables as you did in your second command.

Comment: What _does_ happen? Is there an exception you could post the details of? Have you checked the SQL generated is correct? Have you run the SQL generated against your database directly? What happens?

Comment: Thanks @SonerGönül for responding.. i dont get any error message and  i get no update queries .. i tried parametrizing the variables before that ... nothing happened

Comment: check your where clause maybe your session expired or value of ID is not coming properly in command text, and you can try with all values with parameter including where clause

Comment: Shame on me .. a closing tag was missing... im sorry guys and thanks a lotttt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's difficult to tell what's wrong here but I will gry to improve your code.

Maybe it also fixes the issue.

- Use verbatim string literals, that makes your SQL query much better to read
- Use the `using` statement to ensure that everything gets disposed properly
- Don't use string concatenation to build your SQL query but `SqlParameter`, without exception. That prevents you from SQL injection and other issues.
- Use not `AddWithvalue` but `Add` with the correct `SqlDbType`, otherwise the database makes guesses about the type of your parameter.
- Pass the correct type and don't let the database cast your parameters, that also validates invalid input(f.e. incorrect date)

Code:

```
string updateApple = @"Update Appel_offre Set 
                            Titre_ao = @Titre_ao,
                            Description_ao = @Description_ao,
                            Cout           = @Cout,
                            Type           = @Type,
                            Date           = @Date,
                            Echeance       = @Echeance,
                            Reference      = @Reference,
                            Piece_jointe   = @Piece_jointe,
                            filename       = @filename
                        where Id_ao = @Id_ao;";
string updateLot = @"Update Lot Set 
                            Description    = @Description,
                            Reference      = @Cout,
                            Type           = @Type
                     where Titre = @Titre;";
using (var cnx = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["str"].ConnectionString))
using(var cmd_UpdateApple = new SqlCommand(updateApple, cnx))
using (var cmd_UpdateLot = new SqlCommand(updateLot, cnx))
{
    cmd_UpdateApple.Parameters.Add("@Titre_ao", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox4.Text;
    cmd_UpdateApple.Parameters.Add("@Description_ao", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox5.Text;
    // ...
    cmd_UpdateApple.Parameters.Add("@Date", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTime.Parse(TextBox8.Text);
    // ...

    cnx.Open();
    int updatedAppels = cmd_UpdateApple.ExecuteNonQuery();

    cmd_UpdateLot.Parameters.Add("@Description", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox2.Text.Text;
    // ...
    cmd_UpdateLot.Parameters.Add("@Titre", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Dropdownlst.SelectedItem.Value;
    int updatedLot = cmd_UpdateApple.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

I've used `DateTime.Parse`, use `DateTime.TryParse` if the format can be invalid.

Comment: Thanks man the problem comes from a missing closing tag.. btw i will use ur code .. thanks again :)